# Como rodar um container docker com ownership privado?

Tags: jenkins, integração-contínua, docker

Ao utilizar o portainer.io na versão 1.14.2 e listar todos os containers pode-se ver a coluna ownership. Através da interface do portainer é possível modificar para privado e mudar o controle de acesso para administradores ou restrito para algum perfil ou usuário específico. Como posso ao criar o container através da linha de comando e definir que o ownership é privado e para determinado usuário ou perfil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ownership é uma configuração exclusiva do Portainer. O máximo que você consegue fazer nesse tipo de automação é com a utilização de labels, mas o que você consegue sequer é trabalhar sob o aspecto de segurança, você consegue somente esconder containers criados com determinada label/valor.